# How to enable relation view in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When working in XAMPP with phpmyadmin, after creating a table I have the option to click "relation view" after clicking on the structure tab. See below:

[image]

However anytime when I create a table with my host phpmyadmin, I dont have the option to select "relation view" See below:

[image]

Is there anyway of enabling this? Currently I have to set up relationships in xampp and export to my host phpmyadmin for it to work.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Change your storage engine to InnoDB by going to Operation

Comment: It is already InnoDB but still facing a problem.
I am using XAMPP Server 7 on mac os high sierra.

Answer (score 107):

[image: relation view]

If it's too late at night and your table is already innoDB and you still don't see the link, maybe is due to the fact that now it's placed above the structure of the table, like in the picture is shown

Comment: I just updated PMA and I was going crazy while looking for that option! Thanks!

Comment: In my case: If you just got your first glasses, get used to put them on when work.

Answer (score 28):

first select the table you you would like to make the relation with >> then go to operation , for each table there is difference operation setting, >> inside operation "storage engine" choose innoDB option

innoDB will allow you to view the "relation view" which will help you make the foreign key

[image]

Comment: That was the problem after importing the tables from localhost to the database on the server. It was set to `MyISAM` instead `InnoDB`. Solved, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

**Enabling Relation View in phpMyAdmin / MAMP**

If you’re using MAMP for your database driven projects you’ll probably be using phpMyAdmin to administer your MySQL database if you’ve decided to go down that route. If you’re creating a database you might be wondering how to create relationships and foriegn keys for your tables.

Firstly you need to check that you have access to the Relation view. To do this open phpMyAdmin and select a database. You need to make sure your tables’ storage engine is set to use InnoDB. Click on a table within your database and choose the Operations tab. Make sure that the storage engine is set to use InnoDB and save your changes.

Now, go back to your table view and click the Structure tab. Depending on your version of phpMyAdmin you should see a link titled Relation view below the table structure. If you can see it you’re good to go. If you can’t you’ll need to follow the steps below to set phpMyAdmin to enable Relations view.

1. Find `/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/scripts/create_tables.sql`
2. I left this file default but you can change the table name to anything
   you want. I left mine phpMyAdmin
3. Open phpMyAdmin and go to the **Import** tab.
4. Click the browse button and find the create_tables.sql file and then click **Go**.
5. The tables required for Relation view will be added to the database you specified.
6. Open `/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`
7. Find the Server(s) configuration code block and replace/uncomment the following code and fill in the values. If you left everything default in the create_tables.sql file then you should just cut and paste the lines below.

   > ```
   > $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
   > $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
   > $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
   > $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
   > $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
   > $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
   > $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
   > $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
   > ```
8. Save the file and **restart MAMP** and refresh your phpMyAdmin console.
9. Go to your database and view one of your tables in Structure mode. You should now see the Relation view link.

Source: http://newvibes.com/blog/enabling-relation-view-in-phpmyadmin-mamp/

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the detailed instructions!  The only difference for me was that my create_tables.sql file was located in /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/sql

Answer (score 4):

first ensure that your table **storage engine type should be innoDB** (you can set it using Table operations Tab)
[image]

if you are using **new phpmyadmin then use new "Relation view" tab** to make foreign key relation

[image]

if you are using **old version of phpmyadmin then the "relation view" button will show on the bottom** of the table columns

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1 - Change Your tables search engine from 'My ISAM' to 'Inno DB' by Operations tab
2 - you must do this for all tables that you want make relationship between
3 - **localhost/phpmyadmin/tbl_relation.php?db=your_database_name&table=your_table_name** then replace this url in browser, then you will be able to see the relationship page