# trouble with enabling relation view in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Sorry to post the same question as here ([How to enable relation view in phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420183/how-to-enable-relation-view-in-phpmyadmin)) but it's marked unanswered and none of the provided answers resolve my issue.

My problem is that I do not have a button 'relation view' in the Structure tab of my database in phpmyadmin. I am on Mac OS X, mysql version 5.6.19. The storage of the relevant tables are listed as 'InnoDB' under Operations, as suggested in the first answer of the other question.

I have followed the instructions here:
http://www.w3expert.com/2008/03/how-to-enable-view-feature-in.html
as recommended in the second answer of the question above, restarted machine, still no 'relation view'.

The most elaborate instructions that I have found are these:
http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage
which suggest there is another step after following the instructions on w3expert.com:

"After having imported the examples/create_tables.sql file, you should specify the table names in your config.inc.php file. The directives used for that can be found in the Configuration."

I take this to mean that after following w3expert.com's instructions, the tables are now stored separately, and I need to point phpmyadmin toward them. Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to enable the 'relation view' button by following the instructions here:

http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/pma_config.php

with a few changes:
left out " GRANT SELECT ON mysql.host TO 'pma'@'localhost'; " from the permissions settings
set the host differently: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'

Comment: Hey, I'm having a very similar problem, but even after trying the tutorial you listed, I can't get "relation view" to show up in the database I want it to. My question is here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653382/how-to-display-relation-view-in-mysql-using-myphpadmin-in-mamp). I would really appreciate it if you could have a look and see if I missed something?

Comment: Hi Shirley, I'd be happy to help but it's been too long, I haven't touched phpmyadmin for months... sorry. Hope you get some answers soon; keep at it!