# How to display Relation View in MySQL using phpMyAdmin in MAMP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

Ok, I've working with my database, and I've got 2 tables and I'm trying to create a foreign link between the two. Apparently this means I need a button called Relation View that is only visible after you set both tables to InnoDB under Operations, which I have done. But Relation View failed to show up, either at the top under the "Structure" tab, or at the bottom next to the "Print" icon where it's supposed to be. So I went here (http://www.w3expert.com/2008/03/how-to-enable-view-feature-in.html) and followed the directions to install the phpmyadmin database, which should have enabled the Relation View, but it didn't. So I'm lost. Am i missing something? Is there another way to get this to work?

To be clear, I'm working through phpMyAdmin through my MAMP server.

**Edit** - I've also followed the instructions on this website (http://newvibes.com/blog/enabling-relation-view-in-phpmyadmin-mamp/) and edited the server configurations in the mentioned file.

So to recap -
I've created the phpmyadmin database as per the instructions in the 1st link. Then I changed the configurations of the file mention in the 2nd link. Then I closed my phpMyAdmin and restarted my MAMP server. Reopened everything, and I still can't access my Relation View.

**2nd Edit** - I've been messing with phpMyAdmin, and I've noticed that "Relation View" actually pops up under the database that I imported. But it doesn't show up under any of the other databases. Am I supposed to create my databases in/under the database I imported? If so, how do I do that . . .?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using MyISAM storage engine? phpMyAdmin only shows relational view with InnoDB.

Click on a table, go to Operations at the top and change Storage Engine to InnoDB. I think you can only do this one table at a time

InnoDSB has a lot of overheads for larger databases (so I understand) but should be fine for small/medium stuff.