# Cannot access relation view phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been looking around a few places to figure out why I cannot access the relation view link under the structure tab on phpMyAdmin.

Currently, I have set my storage engine to InnoDB, however, I still do not have the option for relation view.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try some of the alternate answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420183/how-to-enable-relation-view-in-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a bit of a rookie error, the relation view button has changed and I have found it now. View the screenie below:

[Relation View Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tnwF.png)