# How can I see relationship between tables in designer phpmyadmin?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I just added few tables in the database but there are associations between them. I wanted to see the relations in designer but I only found tables and not the associations between them. I have looked for solutions but only found other users having the same issue.
This is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWjK3.png) 
new [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zkIJ.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable relation view in phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420183/how-to-enable-relation-view-in-phpmyadmin)

Comment: no that is already displayed, I updated my question with another screenshot

Comment: just figured it out. Just paste this code in your persistence.xml file
 <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>